# Conditional compilation of SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

**Short version:** Is there some way to conditionally compile chunks of TSQL code in a SQL Server Data Project using SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2010?

I'm using SQL Server Data Tools in Visual Studio 2010 to work on an experimental SQL Server Express database. The eventual destination if things work well would be an enterprise SQL Server platform. I have both a 2008 instance on one box and a 2012 instance on another, because my company is in the process of migrating from 2008 to 2012 for the many enterprise databases as well.

In other programming languages I have used, [preprocessor directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx) make it easy to conditionally compile parts of a code base. The most common uses for this are to have [different code for different platforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg264731%28v=office.14%29.aspx) in restricted sections or to [excluded debugging output code from release builds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/64yxa344.aspx).

Both of these could be very helpful in some store procedures I'm working on. Is there anything like this available? I know I can use `sqlcmd` variables to swap out specific values during deployment, but I can't figure how to use that to include or exclude subsequent chunks of code.

Example:

```sql
#IF $(DebugVersion) = 'True'
    -- A bunch of useful PRINTs and what not
#ELSE
    SET NOCOUNT ON
#ENDIF

#IF $(SSVersion) = '2012'
    SET @pretty_date = FORMAT(@some_date, 'dddd, MMM dd, yyyy')
#ELSE
    SET @pretty_date = CAST(@some_date AS nvarchar(12))
#ENDIF
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not aware of this being possible with SSDT unfortunately.

Depending on how big the project is and how many procedures you intend to enhance with 2012 goodies, it may be manageable with [Composite Projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ssdt/composite-projects-and-schema-compare).

> SSDT can combine a database project with one or more referenced
> database projects or dacpacs to describe a single composite database
> schema.   Using a composite project allows a large database to be
> broken down into more manageable chunks, allows different people or
> teams to have responsibility for different parts of the overall
> schema, and enables reuse of database object definitions in multiple
> databases.

The notion would be to have a base project, containing the common object definitions and version specific projects for procedures that used new features. The 2012 project would reference the base project and a compile/build would combine objects from both.

The PITA would be that you can't override an object in the base project with an object in a composite, so you would have to maintain base, 2008 & 2012 projects. When you wanted a 2012 version of a particular procedure, you would have to remove it from base and create a version in both 2008 & 2012 projects.

Answer (score 2):

I have had an open discussion on MSDN about this need. Have not made much progress. The ideal situation would allow you to flag db objects as "inheritable" in base ssdt projects so that other projects that reference the base project or DAC won't complain of the duplicate object, and would only create the base object or "stub" if it did not exist. This would allow you to have "layers" of database models. See my post on msdn [Extending SSDT Composite Solutions with Overriden Stored Procedures](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/01d69555-82a3-49e2-8ec6-0b896efe6fcc/extending-ssdt-composite-solutions-with-overriden-stored-procedures)

Answer (score 2):

I achieved something close to what is being asked by using prebuild events.  In my case I wanted different users and logins to be included in a deployment according to which configuration was being built.

To do this I created a .sql file for each build config, for each user. I flagged these as Build Action 'None': (I put these in a subfolder of the project)

- Debug_SomeUser.sql
- Release_SomeUser.sql

I then created an empty file *SomeUser.sql* (with Build Action = 'Build').

In the Pre-build event command line :

```
Copy $(ProjectDir)subfolder\$(Configuration)_Someuser.sql $(ProjectDir)Someuser.sql
```

It was a nuisance that a team of coders was constantly creating conflicts in git, so I also added to the pre-build command line

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged $(ProjectDir)Someuser.sql
```

It was fairly fiddly to get this working as I had a much larger number of users and configs to consider, but it works.